# AJAX response that i can't understand 

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 questions :

If i send the ajax request to self page (from abc.php to abc.php) like this :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

What will `msg` variable contain if I have a full webpage (with div's , forms, imgs) ? Will it contain the whole html code source ? How to tell ajax to return only specific details (like for example a php `$variable` after querying a database for a record based on `Name` and `Location`) . Remember some.php is the same file that contains the ajax script.

I want to make a .php script that contains all querys posible to manage a database like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] == 'insert') { code here .. and echo div`s .. etc) }
if(isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] == 'del') { code here .. and echo div`s .. etc) }
if(isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] == 'update') { code here .. and echo div`s .. etc) }
if(isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] == 'find') { code here .. and echo div`s .. etc) }
if(isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] == 'abc') { code here .. and echo div`s .. etc) }
```

and i want to run ajax request based on `option` and retrive specific results (like php $variables ... and so on)

How do i do that ?

Anyway the most important question is how to i get ajax.result that contain just a php `$variable` or an `$array` if the page that receive ajax request already contains `<html><body><divs><tables><h4><h3>.... etc` ?

Because `jquery.ajax()` has a documentation quite complex/complicated on it's options like `accepts, async, complete, contentType, context .. and so on`.

?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataType option to specify the type of data that you are expecting back from the server. In your case JSON might be a good option since the php page can return a String in the form:

```
  {name:value}
```

that that is easy to process as a JSON object on the client.

e.g. [Found on this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   success: callback
 });
```

Your callback function will then process the JSON and retrieve the value. As you can see from the link, you can use the getJSON() method as a shortcut.

Comment: I understood that .. but let's say i want to request from a page that has a lot of html in it. How do i request only the `values` contained in a `div` with a specific `id or class` ? The page that i want to ajax to generates massive html ...

Comment: You cannot. You need to write a separate page that will return only what you want. Alternatively you may want to place some conditional statements in the page to conditionally return the data that you want.

Comment: Alternatively you may have to parse the html returned but that is waaaay too troublesome and inefficient

Comment: Ufff, i understand that now .. yess parsing html with `jquery.find()` and retriving the whole html code isn't to practical ..

Answer (score 1):

The response variable `msg` will contain the full html of the page you have requested.  To get a php variable instead, you need to pack up the variable in a way that javascript can understand, which usually means serializing the object / variable in a json format and then using `$.parseJSON` or `eval` on `msg` to turn the resultant string into a javascript object / array.

Comment: then i guess the `dataType` will be `json`?  Can't i receive only the content of a specific `<div id='id_no'>` ? I guess that the only way of doing this is to receive the whole html and then to append a `jquery.find()` on it ?

Comment: you can do that.  just make your php script only output the contents of <div id='id_no'> based on some condition of the input

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, don't make an ajax request to a page that already contains `<html><body` etc, use a page without that stuff.

All you need is

```
echo $variable;
```